# how can i display the value from tsv file when i have # in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a table from tsv file with d3 table object. some of the sub headers in the tsv file have escape character (#,>,%). When i am trying to create the td  values with function, it does not know how to read the speciale characters and therefore shows nothing. Somebody knows how to sign the special charecters in the d3 function? I used:

```
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) { return [ d.**#attributes**,d.total]; })
       .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

Comment: can you also share your tsv file..

Comment: I can give an example:                                                                                 Name1   Name2   links# total%
a       aa      50      0.2%
b       bb      2       0.01%

Comment: well you can remove all the unwanted characters after reading teh tsv ryt?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you are asking how to access a a property in a JavaScript object when the property name starts with a "special" character.  If so, access them with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
.data(function(d) {
  return [d["#links#"], d[">total%"]];
 })
```

Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sueQ3fiY3rUqAbwqeexs?p=preview) with d3.

Comment: Wow...that is great. Thank you!